# MySQL - Update em cada row

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Gente, eu estou a um tempinho bom tentando montar uma linha de código mas nunca consigo o resultado desejado, já **cheguei em 3 códigos porém nenhum dos 3 executa o código para cada resultado encontrado**. 
Está executando o código apenas para o último resultado de quando a condição for verdadeira ... Alguém sabe como coloco isso tudo dentro de por exemplo um FOR para cada resultado encontrado da row ?

**Código 1** *- Ele realmente altera, mas caso ele encontre 2 ou mais resultados com o id_usuario = id_users ele só realiza o código para o último resultado válido.*

```
UPDATE tb_loja, tb_usuarios 
set carteira = carteira + valor * 0.3, finalizado = "sim"  
where data_inicial = CURDATE() and id_usuario = user_id and finalizado = "nao";
```

**Código 2** *- Exatamente o mesmo problema do primeiro código*

```
update tb_usuarios
inner join tb_loja us on us.id_usuario = tb_usuarios.user_id
set tb_usuarios.carteira = tb_usuarios.carteira + us.valor * 0.3, us.finalizado = "sim"
where us.data_inicial = CURDATE() and us.finalizado = "nao";
```

**Código 3** *- Este é apenas um SELECT que montei para ver se está realmente selecionando tudo direito (e sim, está).*

```
SELECT id_usuario, valor, carteira, user_id 
from tb_loja, tb_usuarios 
where data_inicial = CURDATE() and id_usuario = user_id;
```

Alguém pode me dar um help quanto a isso? Não sei como fazer para este código funcionar de acordo com cada item encontrado .. Obrigado

Comment: Pablo tudo bem? Só para tentar entender melhor, o que você precisa fazer (em termos de lógica mesmo) e qual o resultado que você espera?

Comment: Boa tarde caio ! Bom, tenho 2 tabelas: loja e usuarios.
Eu preciso verificar na tabela loja se a data preenchida na coluna "Data Inicial" é igual a hoje, se for igual a hoje então eu pego a coluna "carteira" que está na minha tabela de usuarios e atualizo o valor dela de acordo com x% da minha coluna "valor" da tabela loja. 
Para corresponder perfeitamente as duas tabelas estou usando o "id_usuario = user_id" pois quando esta condição for verdadeira, quer dizer que estou falando sobre a mesma pessoa em diferentes tabelas

Comment: Para entender melhor:
A tabela "loja" se refere a transações, ou seja, TODAS as linhas que tiverem na tb_loja é de algum usuário que está cadastrado na tb_usuarios, eu apenas preciso atualizar a carteira do meu usuário quando a data inicial for correspondente a hoje... Deu pra entender?

Comment: Olá @PabloAbreu. Edite a sua questão e coloque a informação que acabou de dar em comentário. É de mais facil leitura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia,
 @PabloAbreu pelo que eu li nos comentários da sua pergunta você deseja realizar o update na tabela **usuarios** com dados da sua tabela **loja**, para isso você quer realizar um update com select:

```
UPDATE
    tb_usuarios
SET
    tb_usuarios.carteira = tb_usuarios.carteira + tb_loja.valor * 0.3, tb_loja.finalizado = "sim"
FROM
    tb_usuarios
    inner join tb_loja on tb_loja.id_usuario = tb_usuarios.user_id
WHERE
    tb_loja.data_inicial = CURDATE() and tb_loja.finalizado = "nao";
```

Realize o teste do SQL acima se ele resolve o seu problema.